# How to create table Hierarchy like this

Tags: mysql

I have a table of tests which has list of all tests available at hospitals , hospital also provides tests in groups as packages.
an example of test table is given below...

```
Table : Tests
Id    Name
1     Test1
2     Test2
3     Test3
```

I want to create a table named Packages which will have these tests in groups like, i want to create group of these tests :

```
Table Packages:

Package 1   has     
Test 1
Test 2
and so on....

Package 2    has      
Test 3
Test 2
Test 1
and so on....

Package 3      
Test 3
Test 1
and so on....
```

how can i do this in a better way possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table tests
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(200) not null
);

create table packages
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(200) not null
);

create table tp_junction
(   -- if the test and package intersect, insert a row here
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    testId int not null,
    pkgId int not null,
    unique key (testId,pkgId),  -- limits 1 combo to elimiate residue

    -- referential integrity, parents must exist:
    CONSTRAINT fk_test_par FOREIGN KEY (testId) REFERENCES tests(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_pkg_par FOREIGN KEY (pkgId) REFERENCES packages(id)
);
```